# InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel Runtime exception

Tags: android, exception, runtimeexception

In have an application in playstore which fires a Runtime exception. I tried to solve it two time but still the exception is present in application. I am adding the log below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel (Native Method)
  at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel (InputChannel.java:148)
  at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel (InputChannel.java:39)
  at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel (InputChannel.java:36)
  at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init> (InputBindResult.java:68)
  at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel (InputBindResult.java:112)
  at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel (InputBindResult.java:109)
  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.windowGainedFocus (IInputMethodManager.java:735)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner (InputMethodManager.java:1232)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onPostWindowFocus (InputMethodManager.java:1456)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5441)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)
```